# How can I view the current price of an app I've previously purchased?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, price

I want to view the price of Cut The Rope 2 on the iOS App Store. However, because it's an app I've already purchased, the price listing has been replaced with the "redownload" button.

Is there a way to view the current price of an app I've previously purchased?

[image: Cut The Rope 2]

Answer (score 5):

The best place I have found for this information is [AppShopper.com](http://AppShopper.com). They list all of the current apps on both (iOS, Mac) app stores. They track the current price as well as the price history and update history for the app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this natively is use the share icon to prepare to "gift" the app to someone.

It's convoluted, since you need to choose an email recipient, then choose a card before you get presented with the price of the app. You're one click away from doing the gift in some cases at that point.

Answer (score 1):

### iTunes

Your question is tagged iOS, but if you’re open to using a computer with iTunes, the simplest way is to find the app in the **iTunes App Store**.

Right-click it, then `Copy Link`. Paste the link into a browser, and you will be taken to an **iTunes Preview** page listing the price of the app.

[image: Slow Shutter Cam]

### iOS

You can also copy the link using the `Share` button on the app’s page in the App Store. However pasting that link into Mobile Safari will prompt you to open the **App Store**. `Cancel` won’t produce the **iTunes Preview** page, so you'll need to paste that link into another browser (possibly macOS Safari, through **Continuity**).

*Note*: Links from the iOS App Store’s `Copy Link` command are prefixed with the name of the app. You’ll need to edit it out after pasting it into a browser.

### Search

Lastly you could simply use an online search engine to find your app in the App Store:
`"Cup the Rope 2" site:itunes.apple.com`

The quotes should help bubble your exact app to the top, then you can view the **iTunes Preview** shown previously.

Comment: The desktop iOS App Store is no longer available in iTunes 12.7 ([Source](https://www.engadget.com/2017/09/12/apple-itunes-app-store-itunes-12-7/)).

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way unless you either log out of your account on the App Store, ask someone else that doesn't have it installed to look it up for you, or look it up on Google.

[image: Google results for "cut the rope 2 iphone"]